# Remove item from Quote item - Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, quote, quoteitem, sales-quote

Hi I was trying to remove an item from the sales quote item.

```
$quoteItemCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', $quoteId)->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $product_id)->getFirstItem();;
    $itemId = $quoteItemCollection->getItemId();
    $quoteItemCollection->removeItem($itemId);
    $quoteItemCollection->save();
```

This is returning me the following error.

> {"messages":{"error":[{"code":0,"message":"Invalid method
>   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::removeItem(Array\n(\n [0] =>
>   1355\n)\n)"}]}}

If this is not the way,is there any other way to do or what made me wrong here.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code because `save` method doesnot work with `collection`

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(quote_id);
// get item id by your logic 
$quote->removeItem($itemId);
$quote->save();
```

**removeItem**  method code

```
public function removeItem($itemId)
{
    $item = $this->getItemById($itemId);

    if ($item) {
        $item->setQuote($this);
        /**
         * If we remove item from quote - we can't use multishipping mode
         */
        $this->setIsMultiShipping(false);
        $item->isDeleted(true);
        if ($item->getHasChildren()) {
            foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                $child->isDeleted(true);
            }
        }

        $parent = $item->getParentItem();
        if ($parent) {
            $parent->isDeleted(true);
        }

        Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_remove_item', array('quote_item' => $item));
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I have tried a different function where save worked for collection ,To update qty in sales item

Comment: @Melvin try above code and let me know

Comment: returning the same error

Comment: @Melvin check updated code

Comment: This is working now however the sales quote qty is not getting deducted.IShould I need to add a different logic or this code will take care ?

Comment: @Melvin check updated code , that code shows what removeItem is doing

Comment: thankyou.so to remove qty also from quote ,what will i have to do thanks

Comment: It will delete current item  so it will delete the whole row not only qty it will dlt complete item from that quote

Comment: I was just curious about the items count and items qty in sales quote tabel

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();        
foreach ($items as $item) 
{
   $itemId = $item->getItemId();
   $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the bellow code:

```
 $quote = Mage::getModel("sales/quote");
 $quote->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteId);
 $quoteItems=$quote->getAllItems();
 if(count($quoteItems)>0){
     foreach($quoteItems as $oneItem){
         if($oneItem->getProductId()==$product_id){
           $quote->removeItem($oneItem->getId());
           $quote->collectTotals()->save();
         }
     }
 }
```