# How to remove the product from the order?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I'm trying to remove a product from an order, but my code is not working

```
$backOrdersIds = array();
        foreach ($this->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            $oldQty = (int)$item->getProduct()->getStockItem()->getQty();
            $qtyOrdered = (int)$item->getQty();
            $differenceQty = $oldQty - $qtyOrdered;

            //remove backorder items from Quote
            if($differenceQty <= 0 ){
                $backOrdersIds[] = array(
                    'productId' => $item->getProductId(),
                    'qty' => $qtyOrdered
                );

                $item->delete();
                $this->getQuote()->save();
            }
        }

        foreach ($this->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            var_dump($item->getProductId());
        }
```

```
 var_dump($item->getProductId());
```

still returns me all the products, even those that I deleted

How to remove the product from the order?

Comment: This link can help you I think : https://magecomp.com/blog/programmatically-clear-shopping-cart-magento-2/. But instead to clear all, put your condition.

Comment: your answer concerns magento2, i need help with magento 1.9

Comment: Sorry, I read wrong. Maybe this link instead ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161293/remove-item-from-quote-item-magento1-9